# Syntax: Setting the environment variables in Visual Studio 2008

Tags: visual-studio, syntax, environment

I have been trying to add some environment variables in the Visual Studio 2008 for debugging purpose.
This is because I got this warning:

> Warning    The following environment variables were not found:
>   $(DEV_PATH)
>   $(APPFRAMEWORK_INC)

Here's what I did:
I went to Project > Properties > Configuration Properties > Debugging > Environment

And I have tried adding the following (one by one):

```
DEV_PATH="\ProjectName\source\"
"DEV_PATH=\ProjectName\source\"
$(DEV_PATH)="\ProjectName\source\"
"$(DEV_PATH)=\ProjectName\source\"
```

Because this is the path I need to set.
But unfortunately it does not work.
What exactly is the syntax?
As per the link: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173406.aspx, it is:

```
DEV_PATH=\ProjectName\source
```

But, I need to add multiple such environment variables; so, what must be the separator?
Also, please don't tell me that I can right-click on "My Computer" and modify the environment variables there; I want these environment variables only temporarily for this workspace specifically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have written a script that looks like:

```
set DEV_PATH=\ProjectName\source
set APPFRAMEWORK_INC=\ProjectName\app\framework\inc
```

And I run the script in a command console before launching Visual Studio.
Hence, the environment variables are temporary, as they are lost as soon as the console and Visual Studio windows are closed.

Answer (score 0):

I have found that this can happen if you have a pending Windows Update.  Rebooting seems to fix the problem, as then the Update gets a chance to be applied.